# Importing FFI(third party library) into a Kony Visualizer (V8 SP1) Project

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid, visualizer, temenos-quantum

I am trying to add a third party jar into a kony visualizer project but i am not able to find the "Integrate third party libraries option" like it was present in Kony Studio.

After dwelling on the internet, I found this [thread](https://community.kony.com/developer/forum/import-custom-libraries-option-not-available-kony-visualizer-enterprise). It says that importing third party libraries is not supported in Kony Visuaizer Enterprise 7.0.1.

Now we have Kony Visualizer 8 SP1 but i could not find any document regarding integrating "Third party Library" in my project. I am confused if it is supported now?

I would appreciate if anyone can put a light on this topic.

What i really want to do is, Integrate my custom jar in the kony project and call its function on startup of the application.

Answer (score 0):

The option is present in the Edit menu. Edit-> Integrate third party -> Manage custom libraries. (second from the bottom).